# Calculate extrinsic matrix in an eye in hand configuration

Tags: robotic-arm, cameras, calibration, first-robotics

I have a RGB-D camera mounted in the end effector frame of a robotic arm. I know the intrinsic matrix, but I am a little bot confused in how to calculate extrinsic matrix. Is there any packages to do it? Or how should I do?